# Magento 2 : How to get total review count and get ratings percentage

Tags: magento2, ratings, product-review

In Magento 2, I need to get details of how many reviews approved in specific product and how many average ratings percentage of specific product.

How to get this both details ?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject `\Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory` and `\Magento\Review\Model\Rating $ratingFactory` in your construct.

Add this below code in your file :

```
protected $_reviewFactory;
protected $_ratingFactory;

public function __construct(
..........
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory $reviewFactory,
\Magento\Review\Model\Rating $ratingFactory,
..........
) {
    ..........
    $this->_reviewFactory = $reviewFactory;
    $this->_ratingFactory = $ratingFactory;
    ..........
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    ..........
    $product_id = '1';
    $_ratingSummary = $this->_ratingFactory->getEntitySummary($product_id);
    $ratingCollection = $this->_reviewFactory->create()->getResourceCollection()->addStoreFilter(
        $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())->addStatusFilter(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED)->addEntityFilter('product', $product_id);
    $review_count = count($ratingCollection); // How many review in that specific product

    $product_rating = $_ratingSummary->getSum() / $_ratingSummary->getCount();  // Product rating in percentage
    ..........
}
```

Clean cache and refresh it. Hope it will helpful for you !!

Comment: There is construct must be an instance error generate.

Comment: execute this command rm -rf var/ generated/

Comment: Happy coding !! :)