# How to get product rating using object manager in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, object-manager, ratings

i want to get products rating using object manager i tried below mention code but its not working for me please guide me

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$reviewFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Review\Model\Review');

$storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$reviewFactory->getEntitySummary($product, $storeId);

$ratingSummary = $product->getRatingSummary()->getRatingSummary();
```

Comment: fatal error:uncaught Error:using $this when not in object context

error

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @RohanHapani i want to product rating without percentage simple key name rating encode=>4 etc

Comment: warning:Division by zero 
out put @RohanHapani

Comment: Check it now...

Comment: nothing output blank screen @RohanHapani

Comment: Yes. Because, $_ratingSummary->getSum() and $_ratingSummary->getCount() value is 0. First of all, Add ratings and review in that product.

Comment: rating are added i change id out put show 100 now

Comment: Yes. It means there are full rating in that product. 5 out of 5 as like.

Comment: can i convert into 1 to 5 ..?

Comment: Check my screenshot. You need to add that 100 value as width. You can check in default magento product page also. It will automatically set design in star.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this below code :

**Method 1 :**

```
$product_id = '1';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$rating = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Review\Model\Rating');
$review = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Review\Model\Review');
$storeManager = $objectManager->create("\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface");
$_ratingSummary = $rating->getEntitySummary($product_id);
$ratingCollection = $review->getResourceCollection()
                    ->addStoreFilter($storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                    ->addStatusFilter(\Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                    ->addEntityFilter('product', $product_id);
$review_count = count($ratingCollection); // How many review in that specific product
$product_rating = '';
if ($_ratingSummary->getSum() > 0 && $_ratingSummary->getCount() > 0) {
     $product_rating = $_ratingSummary->getSum() / $_ratingSummary->getCount(); // Product rating in percentage
}
```

**Method 2 :**

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $rating = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Review\Model\Rating');
    $storeManager = $objectManager->create("\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface");
    $ratingCollection = $rating->getResourceCollection()->addEntityFilter(
        'product',$product_id
    )->setPositionOrder()->setStoreFilter(
        $storeManager->getStore()->getId()
    )->addRatingPerStoreName(
        $storeManager->getStore()->getId()
    )->load();
    echo "<pre>";print_r($ratingCollection->getData());
```

**Output Like :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rating_id] => 3
            [entity_id] => 1
            [rating_code] => Rating
            [position] => 0
            [is_active] => 1
            [entity_code] => product
        )

)
```

[image]

***Note : Avoid to use Object Manager Method. Use Factory Method Structure.***

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/232400/51810)